# Website not scrolling on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, pagepiling.js

I am not finished with this website yet, still working and correcting the design.

The main problem I have which took me 2 days, is that the website doesn't scroll at all except when you touch the area where the logo o the site is.

NOTE: I am using `PagePiling.js` library

Please try [this](http://urbanphenomena.net/projects/shukri/) on your phone:

Maybe there is a `div` or some tag that is over the `<body>` which doesn't allow me to scroll, or the JavaScript code has some issues.

Comment: It's because of the `touch-action: none` style on your `<div id="pagepiling" style="overflow: hidden; touch-action: none;">`

Comment: @Sebastian that's not the reason at all.... pagePiling.js uses that because it overwrites the default scrolling of the site. A quick look to the [library sourcecode](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js/blob/master/jquery.pagepiling.js) will tell you that.

Comment: Sounds like a problem in your side. As the [pagePiling,js demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling) works as expected.

Comment: @Sebastian You...are AWESOME!!!!